# I can't seem to define a variable to the value of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello fellow programmers, i'm trying to make a website that makes a route description, but I can't assign a variable to the input form.
I am trying to assign the variable "Bval" (B value) To the green select form, and "Aval" (A value) To the blue select form. Could anyone point out the issue in this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selectroomA').change(function() {
   Aval = $('#selectroomA').value;
  });

 $('#selectroomB').change(function() {
  Bval = $('#selectroomB').value;
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function() {
      console.log('clicked');
  if (Aval === "a001") {
            console.log('Aval = a001');
   if (Bval === "a001") {
              console.log('Bval = a001');
     alert('Je bent al in de A001');
   }
  } else {
          console.log('error with if statements');
        }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
      
.map-box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.svg-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}


/* Buildings */
#building {
  transition: 0.4s fill ease-in-out;
}
.building-a {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #455a64;
}
.building-a1 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #1976D2;
}
.building-a2 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #388E3C;
}
#a0 {
  opacity: 1;
}
#a1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s opacity ease-in-out;
}
#a2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s opacity ease-in-out;
}

/* Rooms */
#room {
  fill: #607d8b;
  transition: 0.4s fill ease-in-out;
}

/* Paths */
#generalpath {
  fill: white;
}
.path {
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in-out;
}
#a0path1, #a0path2, #a0path3, #a001pathty, #a002path, #a003path, #a004path, #a0stairpath {
  fill: #F44336;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Form */
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
select {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#selectroomA {
  background: #40C4FF;
}
#selectroomB {
  background: #00E676;
}

/* Buttons */
.buttons {
  display: block;
}
.upButton, .downButton {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #EEE;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.upButton, .downButton:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #37474F;
  background-color: white;
}
#button i {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.disabled {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #CCC;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  float: right;
}
/* Toolbar */
#toolbartop {
  width: 77%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  color: white;
}
.selection {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.selection select {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#A {
  float: left;
}
#B {
  float: left;
}
#submit {
  width: 77%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  background-color: #455A64;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s background-color ease-in-out;
}
#submit:hover {
  background-color: #546E7A;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toolbartop">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="selection">
          <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
            <div id="A">
              <select name="selectroomA" id="selectroomA">
                <option value="null">Selecteer startpunt</option>
                <optgroup label="A-gebouw">
                  <option value="a001">A001</option>
                  <option value="a002">A002</option>
                  <option value="a003">A003</option>
                  <option value="a004">A004</option>
                  <option value="a005">A005</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="B">
            <select name="selectroomB" id="selectroomB">
              <option value="null">Selecteer bestemming</option>
              <optgroup label="A-gebouw">
                <option value="a001">A001</option>
                <option value="a002">A002</option>
                <option value="a003">A003</option>
                <option value="a004">A004</option>
                <option value="a005">A005</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div id="button" class="upButton" onselectstart="return false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i></div>
        <div id="button" class="downButton" onselectstart="return false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit" onselectstart="return false">Maak route</div>
    
    <div class="svg-container">
    <svg class="map-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g id="a0">
        <!-- Staircase -->
        <g class="staircase">
          <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='35px' width='26px' id="building" fill="#455a64" />
          <rect x='175px' y='40px' height='10px' width='11px' fill="#2196f3"/>
          
          <rect x='175px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2196f3"/>
          <rect x='175px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2994E7"/>
          <rect x='175px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#368DCF"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='9px' width='26px' fill="#3E8AC2"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#4B85AE"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#5A7F95"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#607D8B"/>
        </g>
         
        <!-- Building -->
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a" id="building"/>
        <rect x='330px' y='50px' class="building-a" id="building"/>
        
        <!-- Rooms -->
        <rect x='213px' y='200px' width="35px" height="30px" id="room" class="a001"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='110px' width="30px" height="57px" id="room" class="a002"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' width="30px" height="57px" id="room" class="a003"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='170px' width="30px" height="50px" id="room" class="a004"/>
        <rect x='130px' y='200px' width="80px" height="30px" id="room" class="a004"/>
        
        <rect x='185px' y='50px' width="25px" height="40px" id="room" class="a007"/>
        
        <!-- General Path -->
        <rect x='164px' y='179px' width="85px" height="17px" id="generalpath"/>
        <rect x='164px' y='50px' width="17px" height="137px" id="generalpath"/>
        
        <!-- Specific paths -->
        <rect x='169px' y='185px' width="65px" height="7px" id="a0path1" class="path"/>
        <rect x='169px' y='135px' width="7px" height="50px" id="a0path2" class="path"/>
        <rect x='169px' y='75px' width="7px" height="60px" id="a0path3" class="path"/>
        
        <rect x='228px' y='185px' width="7px" height="15px" id="a001path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='135px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a002path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='75px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a003path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='185px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a004path" class="path"/>
          
        <rect x='169px' y='50px' width="7px" height="60px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='163px' y='18px' width="5" height="32px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='163px' y='18px' width="16" height="5px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='178px' y='18px' width="5" height="32px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
      </g>
      
      <g id="a1">
        <!-- Staircase -->
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='35px' width='11px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='10px' width='26px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='16px' height='35px' width='11px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='40px' height='10px' width='11px' fill="#4CAF50"/>
        
        <rect x='175px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#4CAF50"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#41A977"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#3DA788"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='9px' width='26px' fill="#36A2A5"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2E9EBE"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#279AD9"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2196F3"/>
        
        <!-- Building -->
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a1" id="building"/>
        
      </g>
      
      <g id="a2">
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a2" id="building"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what i did wrong? If so thanks in advance.

Comment: Why global variables instead of checking the value of the drop-downs in the click handler? O.o

Comment: @Andreas It was one of my attempts at tring to fix this issue.

Comment: $('#selectroomA').val() instead of $('#selectroomA').value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `.value` to `.val()` as you are using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectroomA').change(function() {
   Aval = $('#selectroomA').val();
  });

 $('#selectroomB').change(function() {
  Bval = $('#selectroomB').val();
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked',Aval);
  if (Aval === "a001" && Bval === "a001"){
      console.log('Je bent al in de A001');
  }else{
      console.log('error with if statements');
    }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
      
.map-box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.svg-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}


/* Buildings */
#building {
  transition: 0.4s fill ease-in-out;
}
.building-a {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #455a64;
}
.building-a1 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #1976D2;
}
.building-a2 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  fill: #388E3C;
}
#a0 {
  opacity: 1;
}
#a1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s opacity ease-in-out;
}
#a2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s opacity ease-in-out;
}

/* Rooms */
#room {
  fill: #607d8b;
  transition: 0.4s fill ease-in-out;
}

/* Paths */
#generalpath {
  fill: white;
}
.path {
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in-out;
}
#a0path1, #a0path2, #a0path3, #a001pathty, #a002path, #a003path, #a004path, #a0stairpath {
  fill: #F44336;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Form */
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
select {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#selectroomA {
  background: #40C4FF;
}
#selectroomB {
  background: #00E676;
}

/* Buttons */
.buttons {
  display: block;
}
.upButton, .downButton {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #EEE;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.upButton, .downButton:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #37474F;
  background-color: white;
}
#button i {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.disabled {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #CCC;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  float: right;
}
/* Toolbar */
#toolbartop {
  width: 77%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  color: white;
}
.selection {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.selection select {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#A {
  float: left;
}
#B {
  float: left;
}
#submit {
  width: 77%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  background-color: #455A64;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s background-color ease-in-out;
}
#submit:hover {
  background-color: #546E7A;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toolbartop">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="selection">
          <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
            <div id="A">
              <select name="selectroomA" id="selectroomA">
                <option value="null">Selecteer startpunt</option>
                <optgroup label="A-gebouw">
                  <option value="a001">A001</option>
                  <option value="a002">A002</option>
                  <option value="a003">A003</option>
                  <option value="a004">A004</option>
                  <option value="a005">A005</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="B">
            <select name="selectroomB" id="selectroomB">
              <option value="null">Selecteer bestemming</option>
              <optgroup label="A-gebouw">
                <option value="a001">A001</option>
                <option value="a002">A002</option>
                <option value="a003">A003</option>
                <option value="a004">A004</option>
                <option value="a005">A005</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div id="button" class="upButton" onselectstart="return false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i></div>
        <div id="button" class="downButton" onselectstart="return false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit" onselectstart="return false">Maak route</div>
    
    <div class="svg-container">
    <svg class="map-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g id="a0">
        <!-- Staircase -->
        <g class="staircase">
          <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='35px' width='26px' id="building" fill="#455a64" />
          <rect x='175px' y='40px' height='10px' width='11px' fill="#2196f3"/>
          
          <rect x='175px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2196f3"/>
          <rect x='175px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2994E7"/>
          <rect x='175px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#368DCF"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='9px' width='26px' fill="#3E8AC2"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#4B85AE"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#5A7F95"/>
          <rect x='160px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#607D8B"/>
        </g>
         
        <!-- Building -->
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a" id="building"/>
        <rect x='330px' y='50px' class="building-a" id="building"/>
        
        <!-- Rooms -->
        <rect x='213px' y='200px' width="35px" height="30px" id="room" class="a001"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='110px' width="30px" height="57px" id="room" class="a002"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' width="30px" height="57px" id="room" class="a003"/>
        
        <rect x='130px' y='170px' width="30px" height="50px" id="room" class="a004"/>
        <rect x='130px' y='200px' width="80px" height="30px" id="room" class="a004"/>
        
        <rect x='185px' y='50px' width="25px" height="40px" id="room" class="a007"/>
        
        <!-- General Path -->
        <rect x='164px' y='179px' width="85px" height="17px" id="generalpath"/>
        <rect x='164px' y='50px' width="17px" height="137px" id="generalpath"/>
        
        <!-- Specific paths -->
        <rect x='169px' y='185px' width="65px" height="7px" id="a0path1" class="path"/>
        <rect x='169px' y='135px' width="7px" height="50px" id="a0path2" class="path"/>
        <rect x='169px' y='75px' width="7px" height="60px" id="a0path3" class="path"/>
        
        <rect x='228px' y='185px' width="7px" height="15px" id="a001path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='135px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a002path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='75px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a003path" class="path"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='185px' width="15px" height="7px" id="a004path" class="path"/>
          
        <rect x='169px' y='50px' width="7px" height="60px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='163px' y='18px' width="5" height="32px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='163px' y='18px' width="16" height="5px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
        <rect x='178px' y='18px' width="5" height="32px" id="a0stairpath" class="path"/>
      </g>
      
      <g id="a1">
        <!-- Staircase -->
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='35px' width='11px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='10px' width='26px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='16px' height='35px' width='11px' id="building" fill="#1976D2"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='40px' height='10px' width='11px' fill="#4CAF50"/>
        
        <rect x='175px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#4CAF50"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#41A977"/>
        <rect x='175px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#3DA788"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='16px' height='9px' width='26px' fill="#36A2A5"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='27px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2E9EBE"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='33px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#279AD9"/>
        <rect x='160px' y='39px' height='4px' width='11px' fill="#2196F3"/>
        
        <!-- Building -->
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a1" id="building"/>
        
      </g>
      
      <g id="a2">
        <rect x='130px' y='50px' class="building-a2" id="building"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selectroomA').change(function() {
   Aval = $(this).val();
  });

 $('#selectroomB').change(function() {
  Bval = $(this).val();
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function() {
      console.log('clicked');
  if (Aval === "a001") {
            console.log('Aval = a001');
   if (Bval === "a001") {
              console.log('Bval = a001');
     alert('Je bent al in de A001');
   }
  } else {
          console.log('error with if statements');
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but maybe you should add some text so other people know what they're doing and how they could apply this into their code.

Comment: Hi Thanks for adding your answer. I suggest you explain how your code solves OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

change `.value` to `.val()`.

See http://api.jquery.com/val/